# SQL Server: finding duplicates between two parameters in different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find duplicates in SQL Server where customers with the same forename, surname, and mobile number match. The thing is they are in different tables.

```
custid forename surname dateofbirth
-----------------------------------
1       David   John    16-09-1985
2       David   Jon     16-09-1985
3       Sarah   Smith   10-08-2015
4       Peter   Proca   11-06-2011
5       Peter   Broca   11-06-2011

addid custid  line1
-------------------------
1        1    0504135846
2        2    0504135846 
3        3    0506523145
4        4    0503698521
5        5    0503698521
```

I am currently able to find duplicates by forename and surname, but if I want to find based on mobile numbers how can I bring it in?

```
select c.*
from 
    (select 
         c.*, 
         count(*) over (partition by left(surname, 3)) as cnt
     from 
         customers c) c
order by 
    surname;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `join`:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*, t2.line1
             count(*) over (partition by surname, forename, line1) as cnt
      from customers c join
           table2 t2
           on t2.custid = c.custid
     ) c
order by surname;
```

Comment: Thank You Gordon, !! the first query was yours too :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, just JOIN on the table. Using HAVING might simplify your query as well

```
    SELECT COUNT(*), c.forename, c.surname, mn.line1
    FROM customers c 
    INNER JOIN mobilenumber mn  ON c.custid=mn.custid
    GROUP BY c.forename, c.surname, mn.line1
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Also, you might need to LEFT JOIN if there is a chance that some records wont be in the mobilenumbers table.